# CSS Transition Validation errors and support / solutions for older browsers

Tags: css, validation, cross-browser

Please see my site at http://www.visioville.fi/en/ for reference (visioville.fi/styles.css for latest style)

- CSS3 Transitions have been used in Front page's newsbox and in Work samples (or Gallery). They work fine on latest browsers, but how about older browser versions (IE for instance)? Is there a code that can be assigned to just certain browsers (for example, could I tell an older IE browser to just pop up the big gallery picture without any "transition", to avoid problems / broken gallery)?
- Is it problem that I'm getting errors from CSS Validator for all of the transitions, for example:

  ```
  .big ul li img Property transition doesn't exist : width 1s ease
  ```

  and my code says:

  ```
  .big ul li img { transition: width 1s ease; }
  ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way, to do so, is to *develop with progressive enhancement*. This means for short: Code your gallery without JS and CSS3 (e.g. open the picture via a new window), then apply CSS3 and then JS.
2. There's nothing wrong with your css. The transition-property is still in working draft, and therefore not officially completed. Thats why the w3c validor doesn't know that new property or the validor does not know this css-shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Because oldrr browsers don't support transition, they will just ignore it, and the style change will happen with no animation.

Regarding your validation: I guess it's because it could be because your validator is not validating for css3? Also make sure you use te vendor prefixes (e.g. -webkit-) or a script like -prefix-free to add them dynamically.